# How do I delete nodes from a connection line?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm trying to delete nodes from a complex connection line; can this be done in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean waypoints in a connector, right click on the waypoint and select "remove waypoint".

[image]

Comment: For some reason that option did nothing for me. I had to drag the dot off the line, then it disappeared. (Only worked on a point that wasn't the largest one at the end).